# Mercurial: collapse multiple non-consecutive commits

Tags: mercurial

I'm often reviewing some issue on which a large number of commits may have been made, many of which non-consecutive. In many cases, mistakes are later corrected, and I'd rather see the final corrected version on the first inspection.

At the moment in time that I start looking, "rewriting history" is "already too late"; everything has already been pushed into the world (usually by other people than myself).

What I'm looking for is a way to see the joint diff over a number of non-consecutive commits; I may then either choose to actually include push the diff in the global history as an alternative path to the same conclusion (more direct but less true-to-history) or alternatively use the diff as a local reference only.

Does Mercurial have built-in (or other) tooling available for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own answer so far; I'm still very much open to a "real solution" though:

- hg up to the parent of the first commit from the series
- to get the first "graft", some extra action must be taken, because the graft must be different than the original. Therefore:

  - hg export the first commit to some location
  - make any change there
  - hg import it back in
- The other commits may be grafted using the regular hg graft extension
- Use the collapse extension (commenting out the check on "this was created by the current user") to collapse the result

As pseudo-command-line, assuming interesting commits `interesting-0` .. `interesting-n` :

```
hg up interesting-0^
hg export interesting-0 > /tmp/interesting-0
vi /tmp/interesting-0
hg import /tmp/interesting-0

hg id -r tip  # this allows us to identify the new hash of the 'base for collapsing'

hg graft interesting-1
# ...
hg graft interesting-n

hg collapse -r base-for-collapsing:tip
# clean up the commit message in your editor.
# either merge & push; or throw the result away after inspection
```